# SRV record lookup with PHP

Tags: php, dns, srv

If you type

```
nslookup -type=SRV _xmpp-server._tcp.gmail.com
```

(or use the dig command in OSX) you get some SRV records relating to google chat

I would like to replicate this functionality in PHP, does anyone have any good ideas how to do this?

I would like to avoid using exec() as this does not return 100% standard responses across OSX/*NIX/WINDOWS

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [Pear Net_DNS](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_DNS). I managed to get this to work on Linux, but haven't tested it on Windows or any others:

```
require_once('Net/DNS.php');
$resolver = new Net_DNS_Resolver();
$response = $resolver->query('_xmpp-server._tcp.gmail.com', 'SRV');
if ($response) {
    foreach ($response->answer as $rr) {
        $rr->display();
    }
}
```

I modified the example from their documentation. hope this helps

Comment: I would rather privilege native PHP function over oldish PEAR libraries that doesn't play well with up-to-date PHP version. Answer of @Tomalak looks much better to me.

Answer (score 9):

There is [`dns_get_record()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php). According to the docs it can take an `int $type` argument, which refers to a set of constants, one of them being `DNS_SRV`.