# PHP Curl, retrieving Server IP Address

Tags: php, curl, ip-address

I'm using PHP CURL to send a request to a server. What do I need to do so the response from server will include that server's IP address?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This **can** be done with curl, with the advantage of having no other network traffic besides the curl request/response. DNS requests are made by curl to get the ip addresses, which can be found in the verbose report. So:

- Turn on CURLOPT_VERBOSE.
- Direct CURLOPT_STDERR to a
  "*php://temp*" stream wrapper resource.
- Using *preg_match_all()*, parse the
  resource's string content for the ip
  address(es).
- The responding server addresses will
  be in the match array's zero-key
  subarray.
- The address of the server delivering
  the content (assuming a successful
  request) can be retrieved with
  *end()*. Any intervening
  servers' addresses will also be in
  the subarray, in order.

Demo:

```
$url = 'http://google.com';
$wrapper = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $wrapper);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$ips = get_curl_remote_ips($wrapper);
fclose($wrapper);

echo end($ips);  // 208.69.36.231

function get_curl_remote_ips($fp) 
{
    rewind($fp);
    $str = fread($fp, 8192);
    $regex = '/\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/';
    if (preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches)) {
        return array_unique($matches[0]);  // Array([0] => 74.125.45.100 [2] => 208.69.36.231)
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I think you should be able to get the IP address from the server with:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://stackoverflow.com");
curl_exec($ch);
$ip = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_PRIMARY_IP);
curl_close($ch);
echo $ip; // 151.101.129.69
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a way to get that IP address directly from curl.

But something like this could do the trick :

First, do the curl request, and use [`curl_getinfo`](http://php.net/curl_getinfo) to get the "real" URL that has been fetched -- this is because the first URL can redirect to another one, and you want the final one :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
$real_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($real_url);    // http://www.google.fr/
```

Then, use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) to extract the "host" part from that final URL :

```
$host = parse_url($real_url, PHP_URL_HOST);
var_dump($host);        // www.google.fr
```

And, finally, use [`gethostbyname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) to get the IP address that correspond to that host :

```
$ip = gethostbyname($host);
var_dump($ip);          // 209.85.227.99
```

Well... 

That's a solution ^^ It should work in most cases, I suppose -- though I'm not sure you would always get the "correct" result if there is some kind of load-balancing mecanism...

Answer (score 3):

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(gethostbynamel($host));
echo '</pre>';
```

That will give you all the IP addresses associated with the given host name.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can not 'force' the server to send you his IP address in the response. Why not look it up directly? (Check [this question/answers for how to do that from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313880/srv-record-lookup-with-php))

Comment: the server consists of multiple running instances, so I need to find out exactly which server I connected to and responded for a particular CURL request.

Answer (score -1):

I used this one

```
<?
$hosts = gethostbynamel($hostname);
if (is_array($hosts)) {
     echo "Host ".$hostname." resolves to:<br><br>";
     foreach ($hosts as $ip) {
          echo "IP: ".$ip."<br>";
     }
} else {
     echo "Host ".$hostname." is not tied to any IP.";
}
?>
```

from here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbynamel.php