# Without using PECL or system() type functions, is there a way to look up DNS records using PHP?

Tags: php, dns, srv

I'm working on creating a new type of email protocol, and in order to do that I had to set up an SRV DNS record for my domain.

In promoting this protocol, I'll need to be able to discover if a given host uses my system (and if not fall back to an older protocol).

So, is there a way to pull a DNS record (such as SRV) using PHP without using a PECL extension or running it through the linux command line (I already know I can ob_start() and system("host -t SRV hostname") but I'm looking for a better way, if it exists.)

Comment: This was asked before here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313880/srv-record-lookup-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dns_get_record](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php)

```
array dns_get_record  (  string $hostname  [,  int $type = DNS_ANY  [,  array &$authns  [,  array &$addtl  ]]] )
```

> Fetch DNS Resource Records associated
>   with the given hostname.

Comment: Thats only for getting an IP address, not returning DNS records.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that function when I went to the function page for gethostbyname, lol.  Its a new function.  You've been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered PEAR::Net_DNS?
http://pear.php.net/package/Net_DNS

As far as I can tell it uses socket connections (tcp/udp) and decodes the resolver data itself. The available methods look pretty extensive.

Comment: When I said without PECL I also meant without PEAR.  I'm on shared hosting so its kind of a pain to set either up.

Comment: You can download PEAR classes individually. There's no need for server-wide installation through pecl or pear. It's actually quite common to use extracted PEAR classes project-locally. This one in particular is dependency-free.